# Return all cookies in edge browser using chrome.cookies

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Is it possible to get all cookies in Microsoft edge browser using chrome.cookies in edge browser extension. In webextension chrome browser extension will return all cookies when we call getAll() without a cookie url. But, this is not present in Edge browser. Is there any other way to get all the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be **no** at this time (2016/10/8), basically there are two ways to retrieve cookies:

1. [`browser.cookies.getAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll). However, from [Microsoft documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/supported-APIs/), there is a bug for this api which causes it doesn't satisfy your needs.

   > If no URL is provided, cookies are retrieved only for URLs in currently opened  tabs. In Chrome, this gets all cookies on a user’s machine.
2. [`Document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). However this can only be used to get cookies for current document.

Comment: Do i have to replace "browser.cookies" with "chrome.cookies" or is it based on the browser i am working on. If so, then what should i use for edge browser

Comment: `chrome` for google chrome while `browser` for microsoft edge

Comment: I am unable to get url/domain specific cookie as well. I keep getting zero cookies.

Comment: browser.cookies.getAll( { "url" : website}, function(cookies) { });  this returns "undefined" and if i print cookies.length inside the function it returns "0"